# Авто префикс для коммитов mercurial

Tags: bash, mercurial, hg, alias

Как правильно написать алиас для mercurial, который автоматом добавляет префикс к коммитам? Частный случай, название ветки.

В bash все работает:

```
hg commit -m "$(read -p 'comment: ' hgc; echo $(hg branch)$(if [ -n $hgc ]; then echo ' - '$hgc; fi;))"
```

а через алиасы нет:

```
[alias]
cb = commit -m "$(read -p 'comment: ' hgc; echo $(hg branch)$(if [ -n $hgc ]; then echo ' - '$hgc; fi;))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы используете `$(...)` и другие возможности именно шелла в алиасе, то нужно использовать `!`-синтаксис ([shell aliases](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)):

```
[alias]
cb = !hg commit -m "$(read -p 'comment: ' hgc; echo $(hg branch)$(if [ -n $hgc ]; then echo ' - '$hgc; fi;))"
```

(Но должен сказать, что я не смог выполнить ваш пример, который "в bash работает".)